# React project for Neutrinojs displays "Invalid Host/origin Header" in console

Tags: javascript, webpack, neutrino

When I create a Neutrinojs v.9 project

```sh
Davids-iMac-Pro:repos davidedelhart$ create-project test-n9
```

...
    Welcome to Neutrino! 
    To help you create your new project, I am going to ask you a few questions.

```
?   First up, what would you like to create? A web or Node.js application
?   Next, what kind of application would you like to create? React
?   Would you like to add a test runner to your project? Jest
?   Would you like to add linting to your project? Airbnb style rules

  Looks like I have all the info I need. Give me a moment while I create your project!

   create test-n9/package.json
   create test-n9/.neutrinorc.js
   create test-n9/webpack.config.js
   create test-n9/src/App.css
   create test-n9/src/App.jsx
   create test-n9/src/index.jsx
   create test-n9/jest.config.js
   create test-n9/test/simple_test.js
   create test-n9/.eslintrc.js

...

Now change your directory to the following to get started:
  cd test-n9

❤️  Neutrino
Davids-iMac-Pro:repos davidedelhart$ cd test-n9/
Davids-iMac-Pro:test-n9 davidedelhart$ yarn 
yarn install v1.12.3
warning ../../../package.json: No license field
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
✨  Done in 0.41s.
Davids-iMac-Pro:test-n9 davidedelhart$ yarn start
yarn run v1.12.3
warning ../../../package.json: No license field
$ webpack-dev-server --mode development --open
ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:5000/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /index.html
ℹ ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Time: 1814ms
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

I get repeated "Host/Origin header" disconnected message:

[image: error stack from chrome debugger]

What is this coming from, and what does it take to make it go away?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This same error comes in angular also. I know how to handle in angular but I don't know in react. Still I have do some RND on that and I got this.

```
HOST into .env file

HOST=server.com
```

Then restart the development server.

For more info [link](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2271)

I hope it may helps you.